# Dashed line animations in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Is there a way I can do something like this in Mapbox with a LineString?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapbox has recently added an example, in its documentation, on how to do this animation :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Add an ant path animation to a line</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.12.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.12.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #map {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibmFteXNoIiwiYSI6ImNsNm5qYmIwajAxZHIzaXFwOHpraWhsNHoifQ.x6kTRjPrVRWz9JVl_doDPQ';
      const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', // container ID
        // Choose from Mapbox's core styles, or make your own style with Mapbox Studio
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v11', // style URL
        center: [-73.9709, 40.6712], // starting position [lng, lat]
        zoom: 15.773 // starting zoom
      });
      const geojson = {
        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'features': [{
          'type': 'Feature',
          'properties': {},
          'geometry': {
            'coordinates': [
              [-73.97003, 40.67264],
              [-73.96985, 40.67235],
              [-73.96974, 40.67191],
              [-73.96972, 40.67175],
              [-73.96975, 40.67154],
              [-73.96987, 40.67134],
              [-73.97015, 40.67117],
              [-73.97045, 40.67098],
              [-73.97064, 40.67078],
              [-73.97091, 40.67038],
              [-73.97107, 40.67011],
              [-73.97121, 40.66994],
              [-73.97149, 40.66969],
              [-73.97169, 40.66985],
              [-73.97175, 40.66994],
              [-73.97191, 40.66998],
              [-73.97206, 40.66998],
              [-73.97228, 40.67008]
            ],
            'type': 'LineString'
          }
        }]
      };
      map.on('load', () => {
        map.addSource('line', {
          type: 'geojson',
          data: geojson
        });
        // add a line layer without line-dasharray defined to fill the gaps in the dashed line
        map.addLayer({
          type: 'line',
          source: 'line',
          id: 'line-background',
          paint: {
            'line-color': 'yellow',
            'line-width': 6,
            'line-opacity': 0.4
          }
        });
        // add a line layer with line-dasharray set to the first value in dashArraySequence
        map.addLayer({
          type: 'line',
          source: 'line',
          id: 'line-dashed',
          paint: {
            'line-color': 'yellow',
            'line-width': 6,
            'line-dasharray': [0, 4, 3]
          }
        });
        // technique based on https://jsfiddle.net/2mws8y3q/
        // an array of valid line-dasharray values, specifying the lengths of the alternating dashes and gaps that form the dash pattern
        const dashArraySequence = [
          [0, 4, 3],
          [0.5, 4, 2.5],
          [1, 4, 2],
          [1.5, 4, 1.5],
          [2, 4, 1],
          [2.5, 4, 0.5],
          [3, 4, 0],
          [0, 0.5, 3, 3.5],
          [0, 1, 3, 3],
          [0, 1.5, 3, 2.5],
          [0, 2, 3, 2],
          [0, 2.5, 3, 1.5],
          [0, 3, 3, 1]
        ];
        let step = 0;

        function animateDashArray(timestamp) {
          // Update line-dasharray using the next value in dashArraySequence. The
          // divisor in the expression `timestamp / 50` controls the animation speed.
          const newStep = parseInt(
            (timestamp / 50) % dashArraySequence.length);
          if (newStep !== step) {
            map.setPaintProperty('line-dashed', 'line-dasharray', dashArraySequence[step]);
            step = newStep;
          }
          // Request the next frame of the animation.
          requestAnimationFrame(animateDashArray);
        }
        // start the animation
        animateDashArray(0);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Here the link of the documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-ant-path/)

Answer (score 6):

Here's my initial attempt at a dashed line animation using `Map#setPaintProperty(xx, 'line-dasharray', yy)` within a `setInterval` function.

Some rendering artifacts could be eliminated with some creativity and data preprocessing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.34.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.34.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibHVjYXN3b2oiLCJhIjoiY2l5Nmg4cWU1MDA0ejMzcDJtNHJmZzJkcyJ9.WhcEdTYQH6sSw2pm0RSP9Q';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [-122.486052, 37.830348],
    zoom: 15
});

map.on('load', function () {

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "route",
        "type": "line",
        "source": {
            "type": "geojson",
            "data": {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {},
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "LineString",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [-122.48369693756104, 37.83381888486939],
                        [-122.48348236083984, 37.83317489144141],
                        [-122.48339653015138, 37.83270036637107],
                        [-122.48356819152832, 37.832056363179625],
                        [-122.48404026031496, 37.83114119107971],
                        [-122.48404026031496, 37.83049717427869],
                        [-122.48348236083984, 37.829920943955045],
                        [-122.48356819152832, 37.82954808664175],
                        [-122.48507022857666, 37.82944639795659],
                        [-122.48610019683838, 37.82880236636284],
                        [-122.48695850372314, 37.82931081282506],
                        [-122.48700141906738, 37.83080223556934],
                        [-122.48751640319824, 37.83168351665737],
                        [-122.48803138732912, 37.832158048267786],
                        [-122.48888969421387, 37.83297152392784],
                        [-122.48987674713133, 37.83263257682617],
                        [-122.49043464660643, 37.832937629287755],
                        [-122.49125003814696, 37.832429207817725],
                        [-122.49163627624512, 37.832564787218985],
                        [-122.49223709106445, 37.83337825839438],
                        [-122.49378204345702, 37.83368330777276]
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "layout": {
            "line-join": "round",
            "line-cap": "butt"
        },
        "paint": {
            "line-color": "#888",
            "line-width": 8
        }
    });
  
    var dashLength = 1;
    var gapLength = 3;
 
    // We divide the animation up into 40 steps to make careful use of the finite space in
    // LineAtlas
    var steps = 40;
    // A # of steps proportional to the dashLength are devoted to manipulating the dash
    var dashSteps = steps * dashLength / (gapLength + dashLength);
    // A # of steps proportional to the gapLength are devoted to manipulating the gap
    var gapSteps = steps - dashSteps;
  
    // The current step #
    var step = 0;
  
    setInterval(function() {
        step = step + 1;
        if (step >= steps) step = 0;
    
        var t, a, b, c, d;
        if (step < dashSteps) {
          t = step / dashSteps;
          a = (1 - t) * dashLength;
          b = gapLength;
          c = t * dashLength;
          d = 0;
        } else {
          t = (step - dashSteps) / (gapSteps);
          a = 0;
          b = (1 - t) * gapLength;
          c = dashLength;
          d = t * gapLength;          
        }
        
        map.setPaintProperty("route", "line-dasharray", [a, b, c, d]);
    }, 25);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can I define the direction? Or is it random?
Unfortunately the script crashes if "line-cap" is set to round for any reason.

Comment: I just figured out how to reverse the direction. I put the letters in a different order: [d, c, b, a] and it worked :)
But the CPU load is very high at 100% for a few LineStrings. Is there a way to reduce it?

Comment: For anyone finding this, this solution is great but creates a high CPU usage due to map re-rendering. I have used it in my site but had to remove it due to bad performance of the site...

Comment: For better performance, leverage requestAnimationFrame instead of setTimeout.

Answer (score 3):

I prepared a simple animation in this jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2mws8y3q/

```
var animationStep = 50;
var step = 0;
let dashArraySeq = [
    [0, 4, 3],
    [1, 4, 2],
    [2, 4, 1],
    [3, 4, 0],
    [0, 1, 3, 3],
    [0, 2, 3, 2],
    [0, 3, 3, 1]
];
setInterval(() => {
  step = (step + 1) % dashArraySeq.length;
  map.setPaintProperty(layerId, 'line-dasharray', dashArraySeq[step]);
}, animationStep);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. The closest I can think of is to set `line-dasharray` to something like `10,5,0`, then a short time later, change it to `9,5,1`, then `8,5,2` etc.

I haven't tried this, though. It's possible it will redraw in a weird way which doesn't look good.